# How to restart PostgreSQL server on MacOS?

Tags: macos, postgresql

I tried the following and it failed

```
bash-3.2$ pg_ctl restart
pg_ctl: no database directory specified and environment variable PGDATA unset
```

I am using `Macbook Pro` and dont remember the directory where my data is stored and so can't set PGDATA either, is there a way to restart Postgres at all without losing data?

Thank you

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As you want to **re**-start Postgres I assume the server is already running.

Using the superuser account you can query the location of the data directory through SQL:

```
select name, setting
from pg_settings
where name = 'data_directory'
```

With that information you can supply the data directory to the pg_ctl command using the `-D` switch (see the manual for details)

Answer (score 18):

If you used `brew` you could find the restart(start|stop) instructions by doing a `brew info postgresql` Some issues that happen stem from the fact I've seen the plist not load, on OS startup, for some reason. I always forgot what to do and this helped.

on my Postgres 9.2 brew recipe it had:

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Seems that there is very little-to-no brew related documentation on restarting postgres.

Answer (score 16):

**One liner** (with default postgresSql 9.6 install)

```
sudo su postgres -c "/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/pg_ctl restart -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data"
```

**Full version**

Get the pgdata folder (gave me /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data) (thanks @a_horse_with_no_name)

```
select name, setting from pg_settings where name = 'data_directory';
```

For me it returns '/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data'

Then

```
sudo su - postgres
./bin/pg_ctl restart -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data
```

Note: postgres' user home dir should be "/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6"