# How to login postgreSQL in cmd

Tags: postgresql, laravel, homestead

I am a laravel user. I run my project with using homestead, and I am using porstgreSQL as my database. I run `psql -U homestead -h localhost` in my cmd, and then I put `secret` as my password.
But I got an error like this

> psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "homestead"

Comment: The password you need to enter is the password you have configured for your Laravel connection in your app.

Comment: `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=54320
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret`

@CraigRinger

Comment: The notable difference here is the *port*. You haven't specified a port in your `psql` command and PostgreSQL's default port is `5432`. You must have multiple PostgreSQL instances. What if you add `-p 54320` to your command line?

Comment: yes, you're right. It thinks that homestead is using port `5432`, that's why it won't connect. But do you know how to implement postgreSQL in homestead? I can't migrate my database @CraigRinger

Comment: I have no idea what homestead, laravel, etc even are

Comment: I would suggest you `sudo su - postgres` connecting to psql as Os user: `psql -w` setting the password to secret for user `homestead` if such user exists and trying again...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Login Postgresql using command line:

```
psql -U posgtres -p 5432
```

to show list of database:

```
\l
```

to connect database:

```
\c "database_name"
```

to show list of table in database:

```
\dt
```

or

```
\dt+
```

to show list data of table:

```
SELECT * FROM "table_name";
```

Comment: Is `posgtres` a typo here?

Answer (score 7):

For command line, you can try `psql -U homestead -W -h localhost`, that will force the password prompt.

If this doesn't work, read on...

You might need to look into whether or not the user can access PostgreSQL under that username from the IP you are logging in from. For this, you need to look into the file `/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_hba.conf` (keeping in mind that the 9.6 is the version, so your directory name might be something like 9.1 or 9.3). In that file, you'll be looking for a line that looks like this:

`host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5`

That line states that the IP address `127.0.0.1` can log in via port mask `32` using `md5` password hashing. If you need to log in as `homestead` from, say, port 12.34.56.78, you would need to ***add*** this line underneath:

`host    all             homestead       12.34.56.78/32          md5`

After making this adjustment, you need to run `pg_ctl reload` from the command line for the changes to take effect.

Comment: where is the path that I should run `pc_ctl reload`?

Comment: Good question! :) Try `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/`

Comment: I got this error `pg_ctl: no database directory specified and environment variable PGDATA unset`

Comment: SO has answers to that problem in the following links: [Where does PostgreSQL store the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137060/where-does-postgresql-store-the-database/32055424#32055424) and [How to restart PostgreSQL server on MacOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990539/how-to-restart-postgresql-server-on-macos) (never mind that that is for MacOS, the top answer is a solution to finding the working directory)

Comment: Thankyou ffor the reference.

Comment: Providing the `-h localhost` flag should be enough